# How to strip the string which contain forward slash?

Tags: python

i am new to python programming,trying to strip the string which contains forward slash character,i expected output as '/stack' but giving result as below. Could you help me how can i achieve expected output.Is there any other easy way to achieve the same.

```
>>> name='/stack/overflow'
>>> sub ='/overflow'
>>> name.strip(sub)
'stack'
```

Thanks in advance
hema

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.strip` method doesn't do what you think it does:

```
Docstring:
S.strip([chars]) -> string or unicode

Return a copy of the string S with leading and trailing
whitespace removed.
If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.
If chars is unicode, S will be converted to unicode before stripping
```

So what you're doing is saying "remove /,o,v,e,r,f,l,o, and w from the beginning or end of this string."

Instead, try splitting on `/`, taking all but the last element, and rejoining:

```
In [12]: '/'.join("/stack/overflow".split('/')[:-1])
Out[12]: '/stack'
```

If you actually just want to remove the substring '/overflow', you can do:

```
In [15]: "/stack/overflow".replace('/overflow', '')
Out[15]: '/stack'
```

Comment: If he really wants everything-except-the-last, I might use `os.path.split` instead.

Comment: @DSM Assuming what he or she is actually asking is a OS directory path, and not, say, an HTTP path or just a string separated by forward slashes. Besides, that'll fail on Windows: "The os.path module is always the path module suitable for the operating system Python is running on, and therefore usable for local paths." :)

Comment: Rather than splitting and joining, I'd suggest using `rsplit` with a `maxsplit` argument of 1 so that it only splits at most one time. Then you can just take the first value from the result: `'/stack/overflow'.rsplit('/', 1)[0]` -> `'/stack'`

Comment: @Blckknght Nice, didn't know about that.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check which `OS` you are using,

if its Linux/Unix

normally the file path is denoted by `/`

so you can simply use,

```
>>>name = '/stack/overflow'

>>>name.split(os.sep)  # Here os.sep is nothing but "/"

['', 'stack', 'overflow']
```

if it's windows,

just use

```
>>> name.split("/")
['', 'stack', 'overflow']
```